# publish xamarin app in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, xamarin.android, hyper-v

I have done all visual studio 2015 installation process.
So did Hyper-v settings.
Emulatro starts but does not install a program that I have written on it.
Please help to resolve this problem

[image: Below the display is the problem]

Several hours and nothing happens in this case is. The program does not deploy!!!

Answer (score 0):

Would need more details/emulator logs to diagnose issues with the VS emulator, but I would encourage you to disable Hyper-V and then run the Xamarin installer for Windows to get the fast Google Emulators.

They are nice and should fix your problem.

http://xamarin.com/download